# What do you call a group that performs plays (theatre)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a review of the play, I need to list credits for the play.

The person who writes the play is the **playwright**.

What term do I use to refer to the group of actors etc that performed the play? From their Facebook page - they say they are a

> inter-disciplinary Performance Art Collective

What word would I use to describe the group?

ie.

> **The adventure of John Smith**
>
> **Playwright:** Jane Doe
>
> **[Performance Group]:** The Snazzy Art Collective
>
> **Venue:** Some Venue.

Comment: *troupe* - (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/troupe)?

Comment: @GrammarAddict Possibly - though I believe this is a fairly amateur group.

Comment: Think about it: if it was a better word, wouldn't they have used it in their Facebook page?

Answer (score 5):

A "troupe"

this is the term for a group of actors or other performers.

Considering your update (with the playbill), I think that "Performance Ensemble" is probably going to work well given their name.  That said, "troupe" is still more traditional.

If you want to be a bit cheeky about their amateur nature, especially if their visual style is wild or otherwise rustic, you can use "menagerie."   This is not pejorative if used with a warm review, as it renders the eccentricity while valuing their energy.  Though, in your playbill format, it would not be well.  You would use *menagerie* when writing a review.

Answer (score 4):

"Acting company", "Actors", or "Cast"

Comment: Acting company, especially, is the modern term used to refer to a group of actors in official literature.

Answer (score 0):

> **Performers**: The Snazzy Art Collective

You can go minimal because *Collective* in the name says that they are a group.